# In Python, how to import variables defined in a lua file?

Tags: python, lua

I have some lua files that I need to read in Python. I would like to be able to import the variables (mostly tables).

Example of LUA file:

```
print("lua display text")

Civs = { 
    CIVILIZATION_EGYPT = { -- lua comment 1
        Playable = true,
        SpawnYear = -3000,
        StartX = 75,
        StartY = 32,
        Table = { },
        Text = "abc",
        TableTable = { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {}, {}, {}},
    };
    CIVILIZATION_INDIA = { 
        Playable = true,
        SpawnYear = -3000,
        StartX = 98,
        StartY = 42,
        Table = { },
        Text = "abc",
        TableTable = { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {}, {}, {}},
    };
    CIVILIZATION_BABYLON = {
        Playable = true,
        SpawnYear = -3000,
        StartX = 84,
        StartY = 41,
        Table = { },
        Text = "abc",
        TableTable = { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {}, {}, {}},
     }
}
-- lua comment 2
```

If there were just the variables being defined, I guess I could just import the file and it would run as python. But there are comments and even print commands that makes this fail.

Comment: "If there were just the variables being defined, I guess I could just import the file and it would run as python" um, no?

Comment: You would have to write a parser that understands lua syntax. It would be easier if you could use lua to read your lua files and then export them as JSON.

Comment: JSON does seem like it would be the best option here, just want to mention this library: https://github.com/TitanSnow/ffilupa for calling lua from python (do not know how well it works)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no indeed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- read the file from Python and parse the variables into Python variables
- serialize those variables in Lua and deserialize them in Python
- execute that code with a custom Lua interpreter that then provides that data through a Python API

If you want to do this automatically the second approach would require you to parse the Lua code and inject your own so you can serialize the variables. So you could just go with the first way.

Comment: Thanks, I only thought of the third option. But I think the first option (if I understood it correctly, i.e. reading line by line) would imply maintaining and updating the parser each time the file structure is modified, which I don't want to do. Going for the third option.